# Thank you email at office

Tags: phrase-usage, vocabulary, phrases, email

Could you give me better phrases than this?
The situation is that you took 1week leave for vacation and want to say thanks to coworkers.

" title: Thank you

Thank you so much for your assistance during my absence last week. I brought you the XXX cookies from Singapore, which are placed on the desk next to John.
Please help yourself!"

Comment: I think your phrasing and word choice are mostly fine. I would say "I brought you all" or just omit the direct object. I would not use "the" with "cookies". Also I would say "which I have placed on" or even break that sentence into two.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to say:

`Thank you for standing in for me last week. ...`

or:

`Thank you to those of you who stood in for me last week. ...`

Then a slight edit: `I brought you the XXX cookies` should probably read: `I brought you some XXX cookies`